# Calculation of relocation address; ELF

Tags: linux, compiling, elf, linker

I am learning about the relocation from [the ELF reference](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) and [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150324024617/http://mylinuxbook.com/readelf-command/), but I can't get my head around calculating the relocation address.

1. Suppose we have two files `A` and `B` of type `ET_REL`, we want to merge their sections named `S` during linkage; these sections include symbols `SA` (in `A` file) and `SB` (in `B`) file. If we have relocation entries and relocation offsets in `A.elf` and `B.elf`, I don't understand how linker avoids conflict of relocation addresses: I assume that these offsets might be the same in `A.elf` and `B.elf`, since these files don't know about each other during compilation.
2. What is the purpose of relocation table in ET_EXEC? I can't see why is it needed.
3. What is the purpose of the addend in relocation of Rela type?

I think that most of all I don't have a clear intuition on how the relocation looks like, step by step. There is an example in [the blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150324024617/http://mylinuxbook.com/readelf-command/), but I don't understand what happens exactly with that symbol, what is the result and how do we combine multiple sections. Any suggestions on resource to learn would be appreciated.